# updating table with Postgresql Foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql, ddl, foreign-data-wrapper

1. I created a foreign data wrapper table named `t_user` into `mySchema`.

   ```
   IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public LIMIT TO (t_user)
      FROM SERVER myServer INTO mySchema;
   ```
2. The `myServer` side `t_user` added some column, but the foreign table didn't update accordingly.
3. I tried to delete the foreign table `t_user`, but it was used by my view and materialized view `t_user`, so the deletion failed.

Any ideas on how to update this table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have seen, the foreign table definition does not change when the underlying table changes.

If all you did is add a column, you can use [`ALTER FOREIGN TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterforeigntable.html) to add a corresponding column to the foreign table. That should work even if views depend on the foreign table.

For example, if the column is of type `text`, you can do:

```
ALTER FOREIGN TABLE t_user ADD COLUMN my_column text;
```